# Xcode 4.5 doesn't connect the event to IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

Long story short: I had a project developed in Xcode 4.2 for iOS5. I was running it on the Simulator and everything was going great.

Recently I ported the project to iOS6 in Xcode 4.5.1. Soon afterwards I noticed that no buttons (the touch up inside event) were firing their connected `IBActions`. I determined this by placing `NSLog` function calls in the `IBActions`. It looked like as if the connection wasn't there at all, even though I triple checked in Interface Builder that there was a connection.

I recently built a simple test project. A one-page storyboard app with only one button, connected to one `IBAction` on the Touch Up Event. The `IBAction` wasn't fired at all. Then I made an outlet for the button and connected it manually using:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This time it worked - output was shown on the console. If I comment out that line however, it doesn't work, although it is connected to the same event using the Interface Builder. The workaround to this problem is obvious, but also very tedious and impractical.

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you didn't, say, change the names of the functions, or even the number or type of arguments that they took?

Comment: I think that should be obvious from the trivial new project I created. No names were changed, the connection exists. If needed, I'll post screenshots to confirm this, but take it from me, everything is connected as it was when it worked.